# How to mock Net::Twitter?

Tags: unit-testing, perl, mocking

I want to mock `Net::Twitter` in testing, but it seems like I can either mock the methods or the constructor.

My code under test:

```perl
package mcve;

use strict;
use warnings;
use Net::Twitter;

sub mcve() {
    my $twitter = Net::Twitter->new(
        'traits' => [qw/API::RESTv1_1/],
        'ssl' => 1,
    );
}

1;
```

The test case:

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use base 'Test::Class';
use Test::More;
use Test::MockModule;
use mcve;

__PACKAGE__->runtests() unless caller;

sub mcve : Tests {
    my %twitter_args;
    
    my $twitter = Test::MockModule->new('Net::Twitter');
    $twitter->redefine('new', sub {
        shift @_;
        %twitter_args = @_;
        return;
    });

    mcve::mcve();

    is_deeply(
        \%twitter_args,
        {
            'traits' => ['API::RESTv1_1'],
            'ssl' => 1,
        }
    );
}
```

When I run this, it works as expected:

```bash
robert@saaz:~/mcve$ prove -I. mcve.t 
mcve.t .. ok   
All tests successful.
Files=1, Tests=1,  0 wallclock secs ( 0.02 usr  0.01 sys +  0.30 cusr  0.06 csys =  0.39 CPU)
Result: PASS
```

Now I want to mock the `Net::Twitter::update` method and I change my test to this:

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use base 'Test::Class';
use Test::More;
use Test::MockModule;
use mcve;

__PACKAGE__->runtests() unless caller;

sub mcve : Tests {
    my %twitter_args;
    
    my $twitter = Test::MockModule->new('Net::Twitter');
    $twitter->redefine('new', sub {
        shift @_;
        %twitter_args = @_;
        return;
    });
    $twitter->redefine('update', sub {
        return;
    });

    mcve::mcve();

    is_deeply(
        \%twitter_args,
        {
            'traits' => ['API::RESTv1_1'],
            'ssl' => 1,
        }
    );
}
```

But now I get an error:

```
robert@saaz:~/mcve$ prove -I. mcve.t 
mcve.t .. 1/? 
#   Failed test 'mcve died (Net::Twitter::update does not exist! at mcve.t line 22.)'
#   at mcve.t line 8.
#   (in main->mcve)
# Looks like you failed 1 test of 1.
mcve.t .. Dubious, test returned 1 (wstat 256, 0x100)
Failed 1/1 subtests 

Test Summary Report
-------------------
mcve.t (Wstat: 256 Tests: 1 Failed: 1)
  Failed test:  1
  Non-zero exit status: 1
Files=1, Tests=1,  0 wallclock secs ( 0.01 usr  0.00 sys +  0.33 cusr  0.03 csys =  0.37 CPU)
Result: FAIL
```

I found that I can change the mocking to this:

```
my $twitter = Test::MockModule->new(ref(Net::Twitter->new(traits => [qw/API::RESTv1_1/])));
```

and it doesn't complain about `update` anymore, but the mocked constructor does not get called and the test fails:

```
robert@saaz:~/mcve$ prove -I. mcve.t 
mcve.t .. 1/? 
#   Failed test 'mcve'
#   at mcve.t line 26.
#   (in main->mcve)
#     Structures begin differing at:
#          $got->{traits} = Does not exist
#     $expected->{traits} = ARRAY(0x55eaf21d1d68)
# Looks like you failed 1 test of 1.
mcve.t .. Dubious, test returned 1 (wstat 256, 0x100)
Failed 1/1 subtests 

Test Summary Report
-------------------
mcve.t (Wstat: 256 Tests: 1 Failed: 1)
  Failed test:  1
  Non-zero exit status: 1
Files=1, Tests=1,  1 wallclock secs ( 0.03 usr  0.00 sys +  0.40 cusr  0.04 csys =  0.47 CPU)
Result: FAIL
```

I also tried to use `Test::MockModule->new('Net::Twitter', no_auto => 1);` but that didn't make a difference.

How can I mock everything in `Net::Twitter`?

Comment: Net::Twitter lets it stuff happen through the magic of Moose, so that's where you need to look for answers.

Comment: Note that this module has been [superceded by Twitter::API](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::Twitter#DESCRIPTION).

Comment: @DaveCross Yes, thanks, upgrading is on my todo list.